# Execute a command when another command is executed on linux

Tags: linux, shell

I was wondering if there is a command to "listen" to commands on Linux. What I mean, for every time a command is executed, for example sccs edit file, chmod +x file is executed

Comment: SCCS?  I have gone back in time?  No I can't have as I'm using Chrome v27.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes, you have. My chrome is v28. :-P

Comment: @ams Yeah, but when SCCS was still being used, Chrome was v-82323.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `inotify(7)` (there should be a man page) and then choose your favorite language this has an API for (e. g. Python, Perl, C, …).  For Python, see here: http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, it is really old. I am trying to replace it with SVN but it's taking some time, you know how the management always says no to any change.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will satisfy your particular needs, but you might want to consider Linux process accounting... you can get the kernel to write a log file while details of processes run, and if you tail that then I suppose you could trigger some consequent actions.  Not sure if edited files are logged though - likely they'd be captured if specified on the command line, but then they might not be absolute paths which could be tricky too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just for your own use, you can create aliases or shell functions with the same name:

In bash:

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

Then, whenever you do `ls`, it actually does `ls -l` (and any extra arguments are added after that).

Aliases are only useful to rename a command, and/or add a few initial parameters; you can't do anything more complicated. You can make the alias run a script, of course, and do anything you like that way.

Alternatively, you can create a shell function (put it in your `.bashrc` file, for example):

Again, in bash:

```
function sccs () {
   /usr/bin/sccs "$@"
   status=$?
   chmod +x "$1"
   return $status
}
```

I've no idea what an `sccs` command line looks like, so I expect you'd need to do something cleverer in there, but you get the idea, I hope.

Comment: I was tricked into thinking the same mistake.  But the OP wants to be notified when a file changes and then automatically execute e.g. `chmod` on the file.  The change being done by `sccs` is just an example; I guess that changes done by other programs also should lead to that event.

Comment: @Alfe: The question does not say that. Maybe it should? I can't tell.

Comment: @ams Thank you for the answer. My question was a general way to listen to commands on Linux, and as an example, I gave the sccs edit and chmod +x

Comment: Why do you want to listen to all commands if you only have special actions for some? Either you're doing logging, or you're doing "hidden magic", but I doubt you really need to get the two mixed up.

Comment: Then just intercept the ones you care about.

Comment: You should elaborate on the term "listen to a command" because that's unclear, especially in connection with your example.  It could mean "get notified when a file access happens", it also could mean "get notified when a certain program is executed".  Both are very different.  Your example aims for the first, the wording suggests the second.